# Dropping a table with a loadUpdateData changeset in Liquibase

Tags: migration, liquibase

### The Setup

I am using Liquibase to manage my project's migrations.

I have several tables with several sets of seed data.

Each seeded table has a changeset to create the table, followed by a changeset to load the seed data.  The seeds are being loaded using [loadUpdateData](https://www.liquibase.org/documentation/changes/load_update_data.html).  This is a smart method that will load seed data from a CSV, if the CSV content is edited it will make the appropriate edits directly.

The seed ChangeSets are in a separate ChangeLog that is always run after the core ChangeLog.  This way the seed files can always reflect the correct table structure.

### The Problem

I need to drop a table that has seed data.  The loadUpdateData command errors because the table no longer exists by the time it is run.

### The Code

**Create Table ChangeSet**

```
<changeSet author="" id="create-table-help-items">
    <createTable tableName="help_items">
      <column name="help_item_id"
        type="bigint">
        <constraints primaryKey="true"/>
      </column>
      <column name="title"
        type="text" />
      <column name="description"
        type="text" />
    </createTable>
    <rollback>
      <dropTable tableName="help_items"/>
    </rollback>
</changeSet>
```

**Seed ChangeSet**

```
<changeSet author="" id="seed-help-items" runOnChange="true">
    <loadUpdateData file="db/seeds/help_items.csv"
      primaryKey="help_items_id"
      tableName="help_items" />
</changeSet>
```

**Drop Table ChangeSet**

```
<changeSet author="" id="remove-table-help-items">
    <dropTable tableName="help_items"/>
    <rollback changeSetId="create-table-help-items" changeSetAuthor=""/>
</changeSet>
```

### The Questions

Given that it is bad practice to ever delete changesets from a changelog.

1. What is the right way to create seed migrations so that they don't break when the table is deleted?
2. Do I need to keep the seed files for tables that have been dropped?

Comment: Well written question, exactly the same problem I'm having. Shame it is unanswered. Did you find a solution? If you did and add it here, others may benefit...

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem and now i solved it, it works already by me.

The point is that you should set the Rollback in "Drop Table ChangeSet" correctly.

So by droping a table, you should already prepare for the situation of rollback.

```
<changeSet author="" id="remove-table-help-items">
   <dropTable tableName="help_items"/>
       <rollback>
           <createTable tableName="help_items"/>
       </rollback>
</changeSet>
```

Answer (score 0):

I solved this issue by setting runAlways: false for loadUpdateData changeset. So, it doesn't fail when the table is dropped.